# Strongloop Looback Where Or filter in REST syntax

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I need to query `where descr like 'xxx' or short_descr like 'xxx'`

I know [how to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770672/strongloop-loopback-model-find-with-or-condition-on-where-filter) it using:

```
{"where": {
      "or": [
        {"description": {"like": "xxx"}},
        {"short_description": {"like": "xxx"}}
      }
    }
}
```

but need to add query params in REST syntax.

I'm trying:

```
params['filter[where][or]'] = JSON.stringify([
                { "description": { "like": "xxx" } },
                { "short_description": { "like": "xxx" } }
              ])
```

with `The or operator has invalid clauses` result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example (I used 'desc' instead of 'description'):

http://localhost:3000/api/cats?filter[where][or][0][desc][like]=foo&filter[where][or][1][short_desc][like]=goo

So the important parts are this:

- First, you need to give an index to each part of the OR clause. Note the first one is 0, then 1.
- Secondly - um... I thought I had more, but that's pretty much it.

More information on WHERE filters: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Where+filter